# JavaFX FXML Loader

Tags: java, javafx, исключения, maven

Доброго времени суток. Подключил Maven к проекту и теперь MainCompare класс не может подгрузить fxml файл. Пробовал и

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
```

и

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
```

Переместил в директорию класса, всё равно не помогает, вылетает NullPointerException: Location is required.

Подскажите, как быть в данной ситуации?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите Ваш файл MainView.fxml в папку resources maven проекта и получайте его так:

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/MainView.fxml"));
```

или

```
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainView.fxml"));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!:)

Comment: Если подсказка помогла, отметьте как ответ. Спасибо )